# why my code get api but don't show on my document?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, api

My code goes and gets information but does not show it on the screen, I do not understand what is wrong

This page actually takes some information about the country and shows it based on where we are
My code goes and gets information but does not show it on the screen, I do not understand what is wrong

This page actually takes some information about the country and shows it based on where we are

```js
'use strict';

const btn = document.querySelector('.btn-country');
const countriesContainer = document.querySelector('.countries');
// I guess a bug, if there is one, is here 
const renderCountry = function(data, className = '') {
  const html = `
  <article class="country ">
        <img class="country__img" src="${data.flag}" />
        <div class="country__data">
          <h3 class="country__name">${data.name}</h3>
          <h4 class="country__region">${data.region}</h4>
          <p class="country__row"><span></span>${(+data.population / 1000000).toFixed(1)} people</p>
          <p class="country__row"><span>️</span>${data.languages[0].name}</p>
          <p class="country__row"><span></span>${data.currencies[0].name}</p>
        </div>
      </article>
      `;
  countriesContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
  countriesContainer.style.opacity = 1;
};

const renderError = function(msg) {
  countriesContainer.insertAdjacentText('beforeend', msg);
  countriesContainer.style.opacity = 1;
};




const getPosition = function() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject)
  });
};



const whereAmI = function() {
  getPosition().then(pos => {
      const {
        latitude: lat,
        longitude: lng
      } = pos.coords;
      return fetch(`https://geocode.xyz/${lat},${lng}?geoit=json`)
    })
    .then(res => {
      if (!res.ok) throw new Error(`problem with geocoding ${res.status}`);
      return res.json()
    })
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data);
      console.log(`you are in ${data.city} , ${data.country}`);
      return fetch(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/${data.country}`)
    })
    .then(res => {
      if (!res.ok) throw new Error(`country not found (${res.status})`);
      return res.json();
    })
    .then(data => renderCountry(data[0]))
    .catch(err => console.error(`${err.message}`));
};

btn.addEventListener('click', whereAmI)
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: system-ui;
  color: #555;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.countries {
  /* margin-bottom: 8rem; */
  display: flex;
  font-size: 2rem;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

.country {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 2rem 5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  width: 30rem;
  border-radius: 0.7rem;
  margin: 0 3rem;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
}

.neighbour::before {
  content: 'Neighbour country';
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -4rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #888;
}

.neighbour {
  transform: scale(0.8) translateY(1rem);
  margin-left: 0;
}

.country__img {
  width: 30rem;
  height: 17rem;
  object-fit: cover;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-top-left-radius: 0.7rem;
  border-top-right-radius: 0.7rem;
}

.country__data {
  padding: 2.5rem 3.75rem 3rem 3.75rem;
}

.country__name {
  font-size: 2.7rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.7rem;
}

.country__region {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  margin-bottom: 2.5rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #888;
}

.country__row:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.country__row span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 2rem;
  font-size: 2.4rem;
}

.btn-country {
  border: none;
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: 2rem 5rem;
  border-radius: 0.7rem;
  color: white;
  background-color: orangered;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.images {
  display: flex;
}

.images img {
  display: block;
  width: 80rem;
  margin: 4rem;
}

.images img.parallel {
  width: 40rem;
  margin: 2rem;
  border: 3rem solid white;
  box-shadow: 0 2rem 5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script defer src="script.js"></script>
  <title>Asynchronous JavaScript</title>
</head>

<body>
  <main class="container">
    <div class="countries">
      <!--
        <article class="country">
          <img class="country__img" src="" />
          <div class="country__data">
            <h3 class="country__name">COUNTRY</h3>
            <h4 class="country__region">REGION</h4>
            <p class="country__row"><span></span>POP people</p>
            <p class="country__row"><span>️</span>LANG</p>
            <p class="country__row"><span></span>CUR</p>
          </div>
        </article>
        -->
    </div>
    <button class="btn-country">Where am I?</button>
    <div class="images"></div>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If I move the code to my server it works if I do not run it too often, then I get a 403 error. You need to NOT return fetch the second time, just fetch

Comment: And second fetch does not seem to work, I get a 404 and likely need an API key https://plungjan.name/SO/geolocation/

Comment: You probably need to read the licensing/usage terms and conditions for geocoding.xyz and for restcountries.eu. geocoding.xyz for example throttles usage and there are various requirements for an API key/payment depending on what the usage scenario is.